# How can i use a function as a rxjs element in React Native?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, rxjs

I have a separated function class that is taking parameter and which this parameter doing some process and finally returns a flatlist by this processed data. I want to call this function in my App.js and use it as a render element. How can I do that?

Here is my ViewPhoto class

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {
View,
Platform,
FlatList,
Image,
} from 'react-native';
import {styles} from './Styles';

const ViewPhoto = ({imageData}) => {

    let imageList = [];
  
    for (let i = 0; i < Object.keys(imageData).length; i++) {
        console.log('saymaya basladi');
        let data = imageData[String(i)];
        let image = {
            id: String(i),
            contentType: data.mime,
            fileSize: data.size,
            filePath: data.path,
        };

        if (Platform.OS === 'ios') {
            image.fileName = data.filename;
        } else {
            let path = data.path.split('/');
            image.fileName = path[path.length - 1];
        }

        imageList.push(image);
    }

    return (
        <View style={styles.imageViewerContainer}>
            <View style={styles.imageContainer}>
                <FlatList
                    data={this.state.imageList}
                    numColumns={2}
                    renderItem={({item}) => (
                        <Image style={styles.image} source={{uri: item.filePath}} />
                    )}
                    keyExtractor={item => item.id}
                />
            </View>
        </View>
    );
```

};

And this is my App.js

```
import React from 'react';
import {ViewPhoto} from './ViewPhoto';
export default class App extends React.Component{

constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {         
        profilePic:[]
    }
} 

render() {
    return (       
        <View>             
         <ViewPhoto imageData={this.state.profilePic}></ViewPhoto>
       </View> )}
}
```

When I use it this was i get this error.

Unhandled JS Exception: Invariant Violation: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.

Answer (score 0):

Looks you missed exporting the functional component. Change the below line in your ViewPhoto:

`const ViewPhoto = ({imageData}) => {`

to

`export default const ViewPhoto = ({imageData}) => {`